# Lisp Linked List Emulation Java

Tags: java

For my assignment we are to make an emulation of a LISP Linked List in Java. There are two types of List, an EmptyList and a NonEmptyList. The EmptyList is mostly trivial and only serves the purpose of ending the Linked List. The way it is supposed to work is that each List has a head and a tail. The head is an Object and the Tail is the next Linked List. I have a Linked List interface as follows:

```
public interface LispList {
    EmptyList NIL = new EmptyList();

    boolean empty();
    Object head();
    LispList tail();
    LispList cons(Object inputHead);
}
```

And here is the NonEmptyList class:

```
public class NonEmptyList implements LispList{
    Object head;
    LispList tail;

    public NonEmptyList(Object inputHead) {
        this.head = inputHead;
        this.tail = new NonEmptyList(head);
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return false;
    }

    public Object head() {
        return head;
    }

    public LispList tail() {
        return tail;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return head() + " " + tail().toString();
    }

    public NonEmptyList cons(Object inputHead) {
        NonEmptyList a = new NonEmptyList(inputHead);
        return a;
    }

    public class NIL{
        EmptyList NIL;
    }
}
```

EmptyList:

```
public class EmptyList implements LispList {

    public EmptyList() {

    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return true;
    }

    public Object head() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("EmptyList");
    }

    public LispList tail() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("EmptyList");
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }

    public class NIL{
        EmptyList NIL;
    }

    public NonEmptyList cons(Object inputHead) {
        NonEmptyList a = new NonEmptyList(inputHead);
        return a;
    }
}
```

And here is my tester:

```
public class LispListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LispList list = LispList.NIL.cons("C").cons("B").cons("A");

        System.out.println(list.tail());

        System.out.println(list.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is in the constructor of the NonEmptyList. The way I have it currently gives me a Stack Overflow Exception. I have tried a few different things and none of them work the way I need them to. I'm not sure how to make the constructor so the tail points to the next list.

This is my first attempt at a linked list so I might be making a pretty simple mistake.

Comment: Your `NonEmptyList` constructor is calling itself over and over...

Comment: Possibly relevant [LISP linked list with Java](https://common-lisp.net/project/armedbear/).

Comment: The constructor of `NonEmptyList` needs to take two arguments - the head and the tail.

Answer (score 1):

## Short anwser

First, `EmptyList` class needs to be singleton. Not sure how to achieve it Java, but you shouldn't open the constructor to everybody to use.

Then, the constructor for `NonEmptyList` should take two arguments:

1. The object for the head.
2. The tail, the instance of `LispList`. Better if you overload the constructor with this argument defaulting to `EmptyList` (singleton) instance.

Currently, in the constructor `NonEmptyList` you recursively call it when assigning the `tail`: in a way you are constructing an infinite list with repeated element: (a) this is not what you want and (b) without laziness this will cause stack overflow.

Lastly, `cons` is a constructor for a non-empty list, thus there is no need for a method called `cons`.

## A guide into Lisp lists

Most Lisp dialects construct the list on the top of a *pair*. There is some criticism about the way Lisps do it: this introduces concepts of proper and improper lists and it's hard to define a generic comparison on lists. Yet, it's an easy and efficient way to do it.

A *pair* is constructed using `CONS` function (I will be using Common Lisp, CL, for demonstration):

```
(cons 12 45) => (12 . 45)
```

Notice the dot in the printed form of the pair. Parts of the pair can be extracted using functions `CAR` and `CDR`:

```
(car (cons 12 45)) => 12
(cdr (cons 12 45)) => 45
```

Pairs can be combined with other pairs:

```
(cons (cons (cons 1 2) 3) (cons 4 5))
=> (((1 . 2) . 3) 4 . 5)
```

CL provides combination functions of `CAR` and `CDR` to extract sub-pairs, e.g. `CDDAR` is a shortcut for `(CDR (CDR (CAR OBJ)))`: it takes the first item of the pair (which must be a pair itself), then the second item of the result and the second item of that result.

Lisps also define a special object of an empty pair, or nothing (but in fact, this object is not a pair, it's like mathematical "empty set" which is not a set...). In CL there two synonyms for it: `NIL` or `()`.

A list is constructed using pairs ordered in certain way. A list is:

- Either `NIL`, or empty
- Or a `(CONS OBJ TAIL)`, where `OBJ` is any object and `TAIL` is a list.

To distinguish operations on pairs and their combinations from operations on lists, Common Lisp provides synonymous functions:

- `FIRST` extracts the first item of the list (aka head), synonym for `CAR`.
- `REST` returns the tail of the list, synonym for `(CAR (CDR LIST))` or `(CADR LIST)`.

So, here are examples of lists:

- `NIL` is an empty list
- `(CONS 1 NIL)` (printed `(1)`) is the list of one element; `FIRST` will return 1 and `REST` will return an empty list `NIL`.
- `(CONS 1 (CONS 2 NIL))` (printed `(1 2)`) is the list of two elements; `FIRST` will return 1 and `REST` will return the tail list `(2)`.
- Generally, the list of numbers from 1 to `N` will be `(CONS 1 (CONS 2 (CONS 3 ... (CONS N NIL) ..)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct and tested answer:

LispList interface:

```
public interface LispList
{
LispList NIL = new EmptyList();
boolean isEmpty();
Object head();
LispList tail();
LispList cons(Object head);
}
```

EmptyList class

```
public class EmptyList implements LispList {
public String toString() {
    return "";
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object head() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public LispList tail() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public LispList cons(Object head) {
    return new NonEmptyList(head, new EmptyList());
}
```

}

NonEmptyList class

```
public class NonEmptyList implements LispList {
private LispList tail;
private Object head;

public NonEmptyList(Object head, LispList tail) {
    this.head = head;
    this.tail = tail;
}

public String toString() {
    return head() + " " + tail().toString();
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object head() {
    return head;
}

@Override
public LispList tail() {
    return tail;
}

@Override
public LispList cons(Object head) {
    return new NonEmptyList(head, new NonEmptyList(head(), tail));
}
```

}

And test main class:

```
public class LispListTester
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    LispList list1 = new EmptyList();
    System.out.println("[" + list1 + "]");
    System.out.println("Expected: []");

    LispList list2 = new NonEmptyList("A", new EmptyList());
    System.out.println(list2);
    System.out.println("Expected: A");

    LispList list3 = new NonEmptyList("A", new NonEmptyList("B",
            new NonEmptyList("C", new EmptyList())));
    System.out.println(list3);
    System.out.println("Expected: A B C");

    LispList list4 =    LispList.NIL.cons("E").cons("D").cons("C").cons("B").cons("A");
    System.out.println(list4);
    System.out.println("Expected: A B C D E");
    }
}
```